# Determine if OpenSSL uses the CPU SHA256 instructions

Tags: c, openssl, sha256, libcrypto

I'm using OpenSSL (openssl/sha.h) to calculate SHA256 hashes in a performance critical application, written in C. I'm wondering if OpenSSL really uses the [SHA256 CPU instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_SHA_extensions) or if it just calculates SHA256 hash by itself?

Is there a way, to find which way OpenSSL is doing this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to see the port source code as it is open (nomen omen)

For x86-064 you can see:

```
    sha256rnds2 $CDGH0,$ABEF0
```

which indicates that the library uses sha instructions.

https://github.com/openssl

Answer (score 1):

`objdump -d /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1|grep sha256rnds2` would tell if openssl uses any sha256 cpu instruction but it would not tell if or when those instructions are executed. You could start your program in a debugger and set a breakpoint for those instructions.

Comment: what is he uses raspberry pi?

Comment: right. this was for amd64, because the thread author explicitely linked Intel_SHA_extensions. for other architectures other cpu instructions must be checked. also the openssl library may have another filename or may be linked static.

Comment: @mortmann Thanks! I'm actually more interested in arm64 on Mac. Would you know, how the grep statement should be in that case?

Comment: try grepping sha256h